# jquery location.pathname equivalent in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I want to get the url in the search bar using c# basically I want to know the equivalent of  location.pathname in c#

here is the url in the search bar

```
https://localhost:44363/modulotecnico
```

here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test = $('#currentPage').val(location.pathname);  
    //test = /modulotecnico
});
```

/modulotecnico is the result I want to have using c# code in my razor page I have already tried all of this method but none seems to works

here is what I have tried in c# and the results I get

```
@{
    String originalPath = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).OriginalString;
    //originalPath  = https://localhost:44363/kanban/Contrato/19041240
    
    String parentDirectory = originalPath.Substring(0, originalPath.LastIndexOf("/"));
    //parentDirectory = https://localhost:44363/kanban/Contrato

    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    // url  = https://localhost:44363/kanban/Contrato/19041240

    string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    // path = /kanban/Contrato/19041240

    string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
    // host  = localhost
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you rewriting the URL at all? there's no reason why the C# Request URL should be any different than in javascript.You might want to look at Request.UrlReferrer

Comment: I have looked at  Request.UrlReferrer  and the value is null

Comment: I guess my question would be why the URL in your first example (/modulotecnico) is different than that of the c# request. Again, are you doing any URL rewriting or do you have a custom route setup? Is  'modulotecnico' the site name in IIS and therefore is prefixing the URL. Essentially, why should it be '/modulotecnico' vs what c# request URL says?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Request.RawUrl` like below:

```
@{
     string strPathAndQuery = Request.RawUrl;
}
```

Comment: No it does not work i get following url /kanban/Contrato/19041240 I want the url that is in the browser search bar. But thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.